# The difference between "Chemistry students' group" and "Chemistry student's group"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I'm not English native speaker, that's why I'd like to understand the following thing:

What is the difference between "Chemistry students' group" and "Chemistry student's group"?

What is the meaning of the apostrophe in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Please look up information about _singular possessive_ and _plural possessive_.

Comment: See [Apostrophe in “beginners guide”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/apostrophe-in-beginners-guide), posted on ELU before ELL existed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a plural word ending with 's', we put apostrophe 'after' the 's'.

> Chemistry students' group

A group that consists of **many chemistry students**. Here, students are 'plural' and you are talking about those plural students' group.

> Chemistry student's group

Here, you are talking about a chemistry student (one). The group belongs to him/her.

So, to conclude, apostrophe after 's' talks about more than one student (students) and before 's' talks about a single student's group.

Comment: Excellent explanation!!! Thank you for your comment